# Looping throught string - immutability issue

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need one string to be checked and modified many times (searching and replacing different seqences) but it is not working well. I guess its because of the immutability.

```
private string DoRegexCheck(string line)
{
  string pattern;

  foreach (string re in this.regexPatterns.Items)
  {
    pattern = re;
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    line=r.Replace(line, ""); //the line should be updated and the check should continue with updated line 
  }                            

  return line;
}
```

Comment: Strange, it should work. Immutability should not be an issue: the `Regex.Replace` will simply create a **new** `string` instance which will be assigned to the `line` variable. What do you mean by *it is not working well*? What's wrong?

Comment: @Pavel Gatilov: it just does not replace the sequences but it did work when I tried them one by one.

Comment: If you mean "my line didn't change", then simply: your regex patterns are wrong. The code to update line is fine. Please show some actual sample data that we can use to reproduce - i.e. a sample `line`, a few sample patterns, and the desired/actual output.

Comment: (additional tip: please be **very, very** explicit about what the problem you are seeing is, rather than saying "it is not working well")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it is not working well" is somewhat ambiguous.

If you mean "it isn't changing `line` - then that code is fine. Immutability is not an issue at all, since we are changing to a **new** string each `Replace` (the code as shown does not try to edit an existing string). If it isn't updating as expected, then your `Regex` patterns are simply incorrect.

---

If you mean performance: you can't change the way `Regex` works on strings; I would, however, suggest caching the various regex using the `Compiled` option, so that you have an array or dictionary of pre-compiled `Regex` that you re-use. This is especially important if applying this for thousands of `line`s.

Comment: I know, I just need the string "line" to be really updated in each iteration. I think it does not matter there is a regex, it would be the same with any other string altering action.

Comment: @user970696 on the contrary; it very much matters that it is `Regex` because each `Regex.Replace` *takes* a `string` and *returns* a (often different) `string`. Some other APIs might take a `char*` or `StringBuilder`. `Regex` does not. However, I think it it premature to conculde that `string` immutability is the problem. What is the symptom? All you've told us is "not working well". If you mean performance, the overhead of processing those `Regex` without pre-compiling should hugely outweigh `string` immutability. Fix that first.